# Angular2 Web vs Mobile TemplateURL

Tags: web, responsive-design, angular, mobile-website

I'd like to reuse components for a web version of my website as well as a mobile version. The websites are vastly different so responsive design is not feasible.

Ideally, there would be a way to provide multiple templateUrls based on the screen resolution, but I don't think something like this exists.

Example:

```
@Component({
  selector: 'multiplatform-component',
  templateUrl-sm: 'app/sm.html',
  templateUrl-md: 'app/md.html',
})
```

What is the best way to approach this?

Comment: There's going to be platform support for this functionality in the future, [see issue here](https://github.com/angular/angular/issues/1239). So, with all due respect to the answers given, I'd encourage you **not** to put too much time into implementing this now.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could create global function to resolve `templateURL`s:

```
function getTemplateURL(url:string){ /* check browser, etc. */ };

@Component({
  selector: 'multiplatform-component',
  templateUrl: getTemplateURL('app/sm.html')
})
```

Comment: This doesn't seem to work. I get `ERROR in Error encountered resolving symbol values statically. Reference to a non-exported function (position 6:10 in the original .ts file)`

Answer (score 1):

The reusable part of a component usually resides in its class.

You could create a reusable class, that your different components would inherit:

```
export class ReusableClass{
}

@Component({
  selector: 'platform1',
  templateUrl: 'platform1.html',
})
export class Platform1 extends ReusableClass{
}

@Component({
  selector: 'platform2',
  templateUrl: 'platform2.html',
})
export class Platform2 extends ReusableClass{
}
```

All the ReusableClass methods and properties could then be accessible to the `Platform1` and `Platform2` components.

Only the selectors and templates would differ.